# Recourse after recruiter has become unresponsive?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

A little bit of background:

I am currently employed and not actively seeking new employment.  I generally ignore most recruiters seeking to have me interview for those "perfect fit" positions.  This time around, for a variety of reasons, I took the bait.

After learning more about the position, I agreed to take a phone interview, it went very well.  Following that, an in person interview, which also went very well.  After that I had another in-person interview and a follow-up phone call with someone in the HR department of the hiring company to learn more about their benefits and compensation package.

This was about 6 weeks ago.

During the phone call with HR it was made very clear to me that I **would**, in no uncertain terms, be getting a job offer from them.  They had to work out the details to ensure it would be the best offer possible and that it might take some time.

I have been very patient, usually only contacting the recruiter who initially set up the interview once every 4-5 days asking very politely for updates.  In some cases she replies almost instantly basically saying the paperwork is still tied up in their management chain but that she was told an offer will be happening.  Week in and week out, same story.  For the past 3 weeks or so she has become almost completely unresponsive.  I tried to tell myself maybe she was away on vacation or just very busy and not to think too much into it.

On April 1st, as a test, I sent her a friendly email saying that I had gotten a job offer for some huge amount of money directly from the company, followed with a fun "April Fools!" message at the end, she replied instantly about how funny it was, but with no other information related to the position.

A few days later I sent her another email to the effect of "all April fools jokes aside, have you heard anything?", with zero response.

My initial instinct is just to forget about the position and move on with my life, but something really bothers me about this whole thing.  I feel that both the hiring company and the recruiter/recruiting agency have acted very unprofessional throughout this entire process and have wasted a lot of my time.

As I am sure most of you could imagine, the prospect of a new and exciting job can be something that has caused me to lose sleep thinking about, become stressed out over, or otherwise affected my daily life.

My question is:  Should I just forget about this entire situation and move on, or should I make some sort of final attempt to contact either the recruiter, her manager, or perhaps the hiring company directly?

I am still very curious to know what exactly happened and the idea of just forgetting about it is very difficult for me.  I want some closure on this.

Comment: *comments removed*

Answer (score 3):

I've been in the same situation where I'm not actively looking for a job, but a good opportunity presents itself.  I've had interview processes die at all steps of the way, without further contact from the recruiter or company.  Here are some things I try to remember:

### You've still got a job

While you are super-interested in the new position, you aren't desperate.  You still have income.

### You don't want to seem like you need the job

Companies that know you are out of work and need income can use this as leverage to lowball you.  If they sense desperation (**like when you contact them constantly for updates**), they also will know they have the upper hand and can lowball you.

### Ask for updates on a weekly schedule

Remember, you've got a job.  Tell the recruiter you are very interested, but are patient and will wait for the right opportunity (which you think the new potential job is).

Once it's clear the job is on the backburner (like now), I'd suggest sending weekly "update request" emails, and letting the recruiter know when you'll check back.  **Don't let them "don't call us, we'll call you".**  An email once a week asking for an update (especially when they've promised you an offer!) is not pestering or unprofessional.

### Most Important and Most Difficult: Be Patient!

Once you get your mind set on a new job, the current job will get old quick.  Little things that you put up with will start to annoy you more.  You have to fight this and be patient.  Lack of patience will make you look desperate, and that's not what you want.